# Php stream uploaded file from one server to another backend

Tags: php, file-upload

I have php web page with multipart form for file uploading. When user upload file I want to stream it's  content to another backend - Java server. Java server is http server listening 80 port.

I do not want to save the file on the disk on PHP side, because don't want to bother about file names/directories, cleanup etc. I want to stream file content from one socket to another without writing it to disk. Is it possible in PHP ?